# TableView cells with double values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cell

I've got a tableView, with custom cells being filled by NSMutableDictionaries, inside an NSMutableArray.

Now, I'd like to check the `valueForKey@"Location"` for the cell above the one currently being filled. Because, if that location is the same, that cell below should leave some labels blanco.

For example:

```
[Thing on location: Building A  has problem X]
[       and problem Y ]  
[Thing on location: Building B  has problem X]
```

(Yes I know, a poor 'drawing' of a table, haha).

Anyway, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I've tried the code:

```
if ((indexPath.row - 1) > -1)
    {
        NSString *eerste = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[lijstErrors objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 1)] objectForKey:@"Location"]];
        NSString *tweede = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [incInRow objectForKey:@"Location"]];
        NSLog(@"Comparing %@ met %@", eerste, tweede);
    }
```

The problem is, it never gets called. My guess is, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't called for every time a cell is filled in? Any hints on that?

Comment: Can you dump `indexPath.row` before the if statement? And scroll around, this looks correct, still nobody knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's called every time a cell is drawn. Set the delegate of the tableView to your instance which hosts the tableview: in most cases it's self.

Comment: That's done and the table is viewed correctly. However, the NSLog stated in my first post is never called. If I place a new NSLog(@"Test"); above it, Test gets logged but not the compare :( Any idea?

Comment: Ah you mean `if ((indexPath.row - 1) > -1)`? I think I've got you wrong I thought something fundamentally was wrong here.

Comment: yeah, that one didn't get logged, but it got solved as soon as I stopped testing for a negative number! Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: And did you set the datasource?

Answer (score 1):

That's should called, if not may be you have forgotten to set the dataSource. then Try

```
myTableView.dataSource =self;
```

Try with below:

```
if ((indexPath.row - 1) >= -1)
```